# Use Kubernetes Secret as Environment Variable when secret is create from a file

Tags: kubernetes

I have created a kubernetes secret from a file (secret.txt):

```
k1=v1
k2=v2
k3=v3
```

It looks like this secret-:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: secret007
data:
  secret.txt: bWFza1NhbHQ9InRlc3RzYWx0IgpzM1
```

I am using it as environment variable in the pod like this:

```yaml
 - name: KEY1
   valueFrom:
     secretKeyRef:
       key: k1
       name: secret007
       optional: false
```

**Problem**
Problem since the data has a value as a single base64 value. I am not able to refer it in the pod and getting this error.

```
  Warning  Failed     6s (x2 over 6s)  kubelet, Error: couldn't find key k1 in Secret kube-system/secret007
```

Please suggest how to do this without changing the secret format i.e Secret would be a single key value of filename and all secret.txt values as a single base64 value. Is it possible?

Comment: Kubernetes never tries to look "inside" a Secret value (or a ConfigMap value).  You can refer to the entire Secret value as you've shown in the question, but there's no way to tell it (a) that the value is actually newline-separated key=value pairs (as opposed to TOML, YAML, JSON, XML, ...) and (b) that you want to pick some specific value out of there.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. Got it, makes sense to not read secrets.

Comment: Consider posting an answer if it solves your problem. It would be more visible for the rest of the community.

Answer (score 5):

You can create secret entries from environment file

```
kubectl create secret generic test --from-env-file=secret.txt
```

and the output will have distinct values in your secret

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  k1: djE=
  k2: djI=
  k3: djM=
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: test
```

Comment: I knew about this. But wanted to do it without changing the secret format. As mentioned by @david-maze it is not possible as k8s does not read secret and have no idea about whats inside. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

As already mentioned by @DavidMaze, Kubernetes will not to look "inside" a [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) or a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) values:

> You can refer to the entire Secret value as you've shown in the
> question, but there's no way to tell it (a) that the value is actually
> newline-separated key=value pairs (as opposed to TOML, YAML, JSON,
> XML, ...) and (b) that you want to pick some specific value out of
> there.