# Filename of configMap shows up as env in the Pod

Tags: bash, nginx, kubernetes

I have a file named config.txt, which i used to create configmap **myconfig** inside minikube cluster.

However, when I use **myconfig** in a Pod, the name of the file config.txt also shows up as part of the ENV.

How can I correct it?

```sh
> cat config.txt
var3=val3
var4=val4

> kubectl create cm myconfig --from-file=config.txt
configmap/myconfig created

> kubectl describe cm myconfig
Name:         myconfig
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
config.txt:
----
var3=val3
var4=val4

Events:  <none>
```

Pod definition

```sh
> cat nginx.yml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: myconfig
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}

> kubectl create -f nginx.yml
pod/nginx created
```

Pod EVN inspection, notice the line **config.txt=var3=val3**
expected it to be just **var3=val3**

```sh
> kubectl exec -it nginx -- env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=nginx
TERM=xterm
config.txt=var3=val3
var4=val4

KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.96.0.1
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.96.0.1
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
NGINX_VERSION=1.19.4
NJS_VERSION=0.4.4
PKG_RELEASE=1~buster
HOME=/root
```

Comment: This is very similar to [Use Kubernetes Secret as Environment Variable when secret is create from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64803108/use-kubernetes-secret-as-environment-variable-when-secret-is-create-from-a-file#comment114575628_64803108); as I note there, Kubernetes never looks inside a ConfigMap (or Secret) value to try to find a `key=value` pair.  The answer to that question has an alternate ConfigMap layout that should work better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create configmap like this will do the job:

```
kubectl create cm myconfig --from-env-file=config.txt
```